# www.localhost.com redirecting to localhost

Tags: apache

Okay I have my apache server up and running as it should. However I discovered when I attempt to access my live site i.e. www.mysite.com it is redirecting me to my local copy. When I enter localhost it also is taking me to the local copy as it should. Does anyone know why I am unable to access the live copy of my site? Below is the code I have in my USER.conf file if this helps at all. I am using OSX Mavericks and I have read how much trouble it has been causing everyone. Thank you for your help on this issue I am having.

```
<Directory "/Users/USER/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews Includes
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

AddType text/html .shtml .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml .html
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName atp
    DocumentRoot /Users/USER/Sites/mysite/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I fixed it! I was able to solve this issue. It seems the file /private/etc/hosts was pointing to the URL instead of localhost and local.mysite.com. Now everything seems to be working correctly, I just was not investigating the correct file.

Comment: Yeah. It was quite clear from the question that, you local machine host file having temp rule causing to redirect to localhost. Anyway happy to hear that you have managed to resolve it by yourselves.